# How to make InteractionRequest in ViewModel testable?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq

I'm using PRISM and autofac for WPF on .Net 4.0 and I would like to develop an testable ViewModels. For testing we using nUnit and moq for mocking.

So I have a class:

```
public class BackupViewModel : InteractionRequestNotificationObject
   {
      private readonly DelegateCommand backupCommand;
      private readonly IBackupCommandService commandService;
      private readonly InteractionRequest<SaveBrowserDialogViewModel> saveDialogRequest = new InteractionRequest<SaveBrowserDialogViewModel>();

      public BackupViewModel(IBackupCommandService commandService, ISaveBrowserDialogViewModel saveBrowserDialog)
      {
          if(commandService == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("commandService"); 
          if(saveBrowserDialog == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("saveBrowserDialog");

          this.commandService = commandService;
          this.saveBrowserDialog = saveBrowserDialog;
          this.backupCommand = new DelegateCommand(Backup);
      }

      private void Backup()
      {
          saveBrowserDialog.Filters = "Zip archive (*.zip)|*.zip";
          saveDialogRequest.Raise((SaveBrowserDialogViewModel)saveBrowserDialog);
          if (saveBrowserDialog.Confirmed)
          {
              commandService.BackupDatabase(saveBrowserDialog.Path);
          }
      }
   }
```

And I have write unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BackupViewModelTests
{
    private BackupViewModel sut;
    private Mock<IBackupCommandService> backupCommandServiceMock;
    private Mock<ISaveBrowserDialogViewModel> saveDialogMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        backupCommandServiceMock = new Mock<IBackupCommandService>();
        saveDialogMock = new Mock<ISaveBrowserDialogViewModel>();
        sut = new BackupViewModel(backupCommandServiceMock.Object, saveDialogMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void BackupViewModelShouldCallBackupFromCommandService()
    {
        saveDialogMock.Setup(x => x.Confirmed).Returns(true);
        sut.BackupCommand.Execute(null);
        backupCommandServiceMock.Verify(x => x.BackupDatabase(It.IsAny<string>()),Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Now I have yet no idea how to mock saveDialogRequest.Raise(..) so what it can work with an mocking object, not with a real SaveBrowserDialogViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to insert a 'seem' (see Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers) around the static class `InteractionRequest<SaveBrowserDialogViewModel>`.

This would mean pushing this behind an inteface (and implementation) and then registering this interface and implementation with AutoFac and then pass an instance to the ViewModel class as constructor argument. This would then allow you to mock out the interface in your test.

Something like this:

```
public interface IInteractionRequestWrapper<T>
{
    void Request(T instance);
}

public class InteractionRequestWrapper<T> : IInteractionRequestWrapper<T>
{
    private InteractionRequest<T> _saveDialogRequest;

    public InteractionRequestWrapper()
    {
        _saveDialogRequest = new InteractionRequest<T>();
    }
    public void Request(T instance)
    {
        _saveDialogRequest.Request(instance);
    }
}
```